# Unknown URL type: c - Python and Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use tensorflow to generate text, but I can't get the program to recognize the file. This is the code I used:

```
import tensorflow as tf

path_to_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('TheGreatGatsby.pdf', r'C:\Users\Minot\Desktop\TheGreatGatsby.pdf')
```

but it returns this when run:

```
Exception: URL fetch failure on C:\Users\Minot\Desktop\TheGreatGatsby.pdf: None -- unknown url type: c
```

I can't figure out how to format it so that it can read the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs, tf.keras.utils.get_file only downloads a file, it does not search locally.